# LGS Lua - turn toggle into hold

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Hey i been having some trouble trying to turn this into hold, rn 5 is the trigger key and represents the forward side button on the mouse, i press once to activate and once to turn it off but ideally i would like to turn it into a hold

```
Offset = 4
Offset_random = 0 
Btn_main_switch = 5 

Btn_recoil_switch = 4 
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
Is_ads = 0
Enabled = 0
Recoil = 0
Jitter_max = Offset + Offset_random
Jitter_min = Offset - Offset_random


function OnEvent(event, arg)
    ClearLog()
    OutputLogMessage("Current settings:\n\nJitter = %d\nRecoil = %d\n", Enabled, Recoil)
    local recovery_offset
    local downcount
    local jitter
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and Is_ads == 1 and Enabled == 1) then
        downcount = 0
        repeat
            downcount = downcount + 1
            if (downcount <= 150 and Recoil == 1) then
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
            end
            jitter = math.random(Jitter_min, Jitter_max)
            recovery_offset = -jitter
            Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(jitter, jitter)
            Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(recovery_offset, recovery_offset)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end

    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == Btn_main_switch) then
        if (Enabled == 0) then
            Enabled = 1
        else
            Enabled = 0
        end
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == Btn_recoil_switch) then
        if (Recoil == 0) then
            Recoil = 1
        else
            Recoil = 0
        end
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2) then
        Is_ads = 1
    end

    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 2) then
        Is_ads = 0
    end

end
```

there it is

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and Is_ads == 1 and Enabled == 1) then
```

with

```
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and Is_ads == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(Btn_main_switch) then
```